# How were the 10 heads of Ravana arranged?

Tags: ramayana, scripture, ravana

Uttara Kanda (Also other Kandas) of Ramayan mentions Ravana having 10 heads and 20 arms.

Now 10 heads would make a body asymmetrical as there is no middle point.

Is there any mention in scriptures which tells us to which head among the 10 was Ravana's body attached to? Also Ravana is called **Dasagriva** meaning having ten necks. If such is the condition how were his necks attached ?

Were they in linear design or in circular design?
E.g., did his right side contain more heads or his left side (when he used to be in the form of 'Dashanan')?

Do any scripture mention about this ?

Comment: It's an interesting question because the popular representation us like you said ten heads arranged in a row. But the Uttara Kanda actually says ten **necks** which means all heads were connected to the body.

Comment: @Surya Yeah, he's called Dasagriva, and not just in the Uttara Kanda, in other Kandas as well. I'm imagining a central neck attached to the shoulders and nine other necks branching off in all directions.

Comment: @Keshav But the point of a neck is to connect to the body right? I imagine something like the cover art of the Vengeance Of Ravana by Ashok Banker (Google it and you'll understand what I am saying.)